# Ubuntu Gnome status status area cluttered, can it be moved up?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, ubuntu-gnome

I'm a total newbie and I'm starting to use Ubuntu Gnome 16.04

I noticed that the open programs tend to go on the left of the screen and tracking them can be a hassle.

Can they be ported up with the volume and the wifi? Would be a huge help because I tried my best and I couldn't do it!

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for is an extension that will move the legacy tray to the top panel, the extention for gnome is called [TopIcon](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/) and it moves the status icons to the bar.

Once at the site using Firefox allow it to install extensions, and after it's installed go to tweak tool and enable the extension from there.

Good luck.

Comment: This worked for me perfectly, thank you! A great answer and quick response too!